# Is there a format which can store tabular data in lesser size than excel?

Tags: c#, excel, serialization, tabular

I have already tried out keeping in text file(Obviosuly it takes more space as it is not customized to hold tables as an excel is). I also tried keeping serialized data(c#, just an fyi). There wasn't any benefit in either cases.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and why is size an issue?

Comment: Please clarify what you intend to do. Are you looking for a file format?

Comment: I have certain data which I don't want to be read manually. Only my software will be able to decrypt that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since most 'tabular' data will be text, you'll get large gains in compressing this before saving (using GZip and BsonWriter as an example):

```
public static byte[] Compress(object entity)
{
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
      using (var writer = new BsonWriter(zipStream))
      {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, entity);
      }
    }

    return stream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

** Update **

Protobuf is [far superior to both XmlSerializer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) and [BinaryFormatter](http://wallaceturner.com/serialization-with-protobuf-net) in terms of serialized entity size and speed. Try using this to serialize your entities before compressing:

```
public static byte[] Compress(object entity)
{
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
      Serializer.Serialize(stream, entity);  
    }

    return stream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, was going to say try 7zip as that has a good API and the compression rate and options are good.

Comment: I had tried it earlier but the compression ratio was not good enough. I used binary and xml serialization.